# List vs. Map: Which takes less space and more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, list, dictionary, set

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
class Foo
{
    Set<Integer> bars; // Foo objects have collection of bars.
    Set<Integer> adjacents; // Adjacency list of Foos.
}

class Bar
{
    int foo; // ID of foo of which this object belongs to
    Ipsum ipsum; // This an arbitrary class. But it must be present
    Map<Integer, Float> adjacents; // Adjacency list of Bars
}
```

Number of `Bar`s are predefined (up to 1000). Hence, I may use an array.
But number of `Foo`s are undefined (at most `#ofBars/4`).

When you consider addition, deletion and `get()`, I need the one which is faster and takes less space (because I'm going to use serialization).

Here are my options (as far as I have thought)

**Option 1:** Don't define a class for `Foo`. Instead, use `List<Set<Integer>> foo;` and another map for Map> fooAdjacencies;
**Option 2:** Use `Map<Integer, Set<Integer> foo` if I want to get bars of `i`, I simply write `foo.get(i)`.
**Option 3:** Dont define classes. Instead, use option 2 and for `Bar` class:

```
Map<Integer, Ipsum> bar;
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Floar>> barAdjacencies;
```

Which option should I choose in terms of space and time efficiency?

Comment: A Map is *fundamentally different* than a List. What behavior do you need?

Comment: I need my structure to be efficient while adding, removing and finding elements. No other behavior.

Comment: Ref. [ArrayList/List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) , [HashMap/Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - pay attention to the method contracts and the bounds discussed in the class documentation.

Comment: It's hard to find out what you're asking and the reason for this is that you're presenting some pre-optimized solution instead of the problem. I'd suggest to write down the declarations of methods you need. I guess in your problem are no `Integer`s at all. Also note that the serialized form can be completely decoupled from the objects, so the space may be pretty unrelated.

Comment: It doesn't matter how efficient something is if it's the wrong data structure for your application.  And there are many gotchas with serialization... far too many to go into here.  See Effective Java by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it'd be very helpful for you (specifically the Data Structures section): http://bigocheatsheet.com/

You say

> I need my structure to be efficient while adding, removing and finding elements. No other behavior.

The problem is that `Lists` and `Maps` are usually used in totally different cases. Their names describe their use cases fairly well -- you use a `List` if you need to *list* something (probably in some sequential order), while a `Map` would be used if you need to *map* an input to an output. You can use a `Map` as a `List` by mapping `Integers` to your elements, but that's overcomplicating things a bit. However, even within `List` and `Map` you can have different implementations that differ wildly in asymptotic performance.

With few exceptions, data structures will take `O(n)` space, which makes sense. If memory serves, anything other than an `ArrayList` (or other collections backed only by a primitive array) will have a decent amount of space overhead as they use other objects (e.g. `Nodes` for `LinkedLists` and `Entry` objects for `Maps`) to organize the underlying structure. I wouldn't worry too much about this overhead though unless space really is at a premium.

For best-performance addition, deletion, and search, you want to look at how the data structure is implemented.

- `LinkedList`-style implementation will net you `O(1)` addition and deletion (and with a good constant factor, too!), but will have a pretty expensive `get()` with `O(n)` time, because the list will have to be traversed every time you want to get something. Java's `LinkedList` implementation, though, removes in `O(n)` time; while the actual act of deletion is `O(1)`, that's only if you have a reference to the actual node that you're removing. Because you don't, removals in Java's `LinkedList` are `O(n)` -- `O(n)` for searching for the node to remove, and `O(1)` for removal.
- Data structures backed with a plain array will have `O(1)` `get()` because it's an array, but takes `O(n)` to add, and delete, because any addition/deletion other than at the last element requires all other elements to be shuffled (in Java's implementation at least). Searching for something using an object instead of an index is done in `O(n)` time because you have to iterate over the array to find the object.

The following two structures are usually `Maps`, and so usually require you to implement `equals()` (and `hashCode()` for `HashMaps`):

- Data structures backed by a tree (e.g. `TreeMap`) will have amortized (I think) `O(lg n)` add/remove, as a good implementation should be self-balancing, making worst-case addition/deletions only have to go through the height of the tree at most. `get()` operations are `O(lg n)`. Using a tree requires that your elements be sortable/comparable in some way, which could be a bonus or hinderance, depending on your usage.
- Hash-based data structures have amortized (average) `O(1)` everything, albeit with a slightly higher constant factor due to the overhead of hashing (and following any chains if the hash spread is poor). `HashMaps` could start sucking if you write a bad `hashCode()` function, though, so you want to be careful with that, although the implementers of Java's `HashMap` did do some magic behind the scenes to try to at least partially negate the effect of bad `hashCode()` implementations.

Hope that rundown helped. If you clear up how your program is structured, I might be able to give a recommendation. Until then, the best I can do is show you the options and let you pick.

Comment: LinkedList has O(n) deletions

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you already have a node reference or if you need to get it. If you already have a reference to the node it's `O(1)`, otherwise it's technically a search (`O(n)`) then delete (`O(1)`). I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

I find this problem description a little hard to follow, but I think you're just looking for general collections/data structures advice.

A list (say, an array list) easily allows you to add and iterate over elements.  When it is expanded beyond the size of the underlying array, a one-off costly resize operation is executed to add more space; but that is fine because it happens rarely and the amortized time is not bad.  Searching for a specific element in a list is slow because you need to traverse it in order; there is no implied ordering in most lists.  Deleting elements depends on the underlying list implementation.  An array list could be slow in this regard; but I'm guessing that they optimized it just by marking the underlying element as deleted and skipping it during iteration.  When using lists you also have to consider where you are adding elements.  Linked lists are slower to iterate but can easily add and remove elements at any position.  Array lists cannot easily add an element anywhere but the end.

Per your requirements, if you are required to execute a "get" or find on an element, then you need some kind of searching functionality to speed it up.  This would make a map better as you can locate elements in log(n) time instead of linear time as when searching an unordered list.  Adding and removing elements in a list is also relatively fast, so that's probably your best option.

Most importantly, implement it more than one way and profile it yourself to learn more :)  Lists are rarely a good choice when searching is required though.

Comment: I may have chosen the wrong word :) I mean `get()` operation.